# Why my const var is empty but the related filter works

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

```
 RemoveArea(area: models.Area) {
    let messages: string[] = [];

    messages = messages.concat(this.getMessagesFromDeletingArea(area));

    this._translate.get('QuestionGroup_RemoveAreaConfirm',
        { thisCaption: area.caption[this.BlueContext.currentLanguage] }).subscribe(nextCaption => {
            this.dialogsService.confirm(nextCaption, messages)
                .subscribe(confirmed => {
                    if (confirmed) {
                        this._areaService.removeArea(this.dashboardConfiguration, area, this.BlueContext.currentLanguage);
                        const index = this.areas.findIndex(a => a.id === area.id);
                        if (index > -1) {
                            this.areas.splice(index, 1);
                            //here
                        
                           
                            this.dashboardConfiguration.widgets.forEach(wAId => {
                                const allWidgetByAreaId = wAId.widgets.filter(w => w.areaId === area.id);
                                allWidgetByAreaId.forEach(w => {
                                    w.areaId = null;
                                    });
                            });
                            
                        }

                    }
                });
        });
}
```

The filter is working but the const var (allWidgetByAreaId) is undefined and empty so "for each " does not work. Would you please help?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: *"The filter is working but the const var (allWidgetByAreaId) is undefined and empty"* It's certainly not `undefined` (`filter` isn't broken, it **will** return an array if your callback never throws), but it's certainly possible for it to be empty. If it is, it's because there was no element `w` for which `w.areaId === area.id` is true. That's what you have to debug. (My guess: One of them is a string, the other is anumber. But it's a guess.)

Comment: no both are number

Comment: but yes, it is not undefined but empty.

Comment: Thank you VLAZ, you were right, I solved it.